# How to add fields dynamically to snowflake's object_construct function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a large table of data in Snowflake that contains many fields with a name prefix of 'RAW_'.  In order to make my table more manageable, I wish to condense all of these 'RAW_' fields into just one field called 'RAW_KEY_VALUE', condensing all of it into a key-value object store.

It initially appeared that Snowflake's 'OBJECT_CONSTRUCT' function was going to be my perfect solution here.  However, the issue with this function is that it requires a manual input/hard coding of the fields you wish to convert to a key-value object.  This is problematic for me as I have anywhere from 90-120 fields I would need to manually place in this function.  Additionally, these fields with a 'RAW_' prefix change all the time.  It is therefore critical that I have a solution that allows me to dynamically add these fields and convert them to a key-value store.  (I haven't tried creating a stored procedure for this yet but will if all else fails)

Here is a snippet of the data in question

```
create or replace table reviews(name varchar(50), acting_rating int, raw_comments varchar(50), raw_rating int, raw_co varchar(50));

insert into reviews values
    ('abc', 4, NULL, 1, 'NO'),
    ('xyz', 3, 'some', 1, 'haha'),
    ('lmn', 1, 'what', 4, NULL);
```

Below is the output I'm trying to achieve (using the manual input/hard coding approach with object_construct)

```
select 
name , 
acting_rating ,
object_construct_keep_null ('raw_comments',raw_comments,'raw_rating',raw_rating,'raw_co',raw_co) as RAW_KEY_VALUE
from reviews;
```

The above produces this desired output below.

[image]

Please let me know if there are any other ways to approach here. I think if I was able to work out a way to add the relevant fields to the object_construct function dynamically, that would solve my problem.

Comment: Is there a primary key on this table -- something that uniquely identifies a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a JS UDF and `object_construct(*)`:

```sql
create or replace function obj_with_prefix(PREFIX string, A variant)
returns variant
language javascript
as $$
let result = {};

for (key in A) {
  if (key.startsWith(PREFIX))
      result[key] = A[key];
}

return result
$$
;
```

Test:

```sql
with data(aa_1, aa_2, bb_1, aa_3) as (
    select 1,2,3,4
)


select obj_with_prefix('AA', object_construct(*))
from data
```

[image]

Comment: This is great and gets me 50% there.  Within this UDF you created ,is there a way to dynamically add the 'non' prefixed fields within the select statement? something like this.. ``` select bb_1 , obj_with_prefix('AA', object_construct(*))
from data```

Comment: That's exactly how it should work!

Comment: yes, but I was hoping to add these non-prefixed fields dynamically as well because I have about 50-60 of these to add (normally).  You have given me the idea of creating a seperate UDF that selects the non-prefixed fields as well

Comment: @jwlon81 that would work, but you would get them as an object too (you can't get an unknown number of columns in SQL, usually)

Comment: (btw, that second part is not contained in the question here, so please upvote and accept this answer if it answers the question you asked)